# how to change the date format in desired output;

Tags: java, android, calendar

I got stuck while changing the date format ,
my string is like which i am  getting

```
 sat,05 sep 2014
```

how do i get the each values after comma like this

```
5 
september

2015
```

Comment: how you want it to be formatted?

Answer (score 2):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
final String first_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
final String second_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";


String oldDateString = "27/01/2014";
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(first_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(second_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

how did you get the string? 
Maybe SimpleDateFormat can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not directly clear what exactly You want, but I suspect, that the String You get:  **sat,05 sep 2014**, must be a SimpleDateFormat similar to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM yyyy");
```

So if You want to have a date like **5 September 2015**, it must be:

```
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

So a possible way should be:

```
Date oldFormattedDate = oldFormat.parse(YourOldDateString);

String newFormattedString = newFormat.format(oldFormattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving Leyonce's answer above, you can actually use `substring` to actually get the individual date elements.

```
final String originalFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy";   
    final String desiredFormat = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(originalFormat);
    String inputDate = "sat, 05 sep 2014";


    Date date = sdf.parse(inputDate);
    sdf.applyPattern(desiredFormat);
    String dateString = sdf.format(date);

    String parsedDate = dateString.substring(0, 2);
    String parsedMonth = dateString.substring(3, dateString.lastIndexOf(" "));
    String parsedYear = dateString.substring(dateString.lastIndexOf(" ")+1 , dateString.length());

    System.out.println(parsedDate);
    System.out.println(parsedMonth);
    System.out.println(parsedYear);
```

the output should be:

```
05
September
2014
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i am getting answer like 05 s 2014. How do i get the full month String.

Comment: make sure of your format: `final String desiredFormat = "dd MMMMM yyyy";` Also check how you use substring(first position, last position)